# Spring Boot 2 not triggering @CircuitBreaker of resilience4j when calling a servlet from service methods

Tags: spring-boot, httpclient, spring-cloud, java-11, resilience4j

I am trying to implement resilience4j in Spring Boot 2 application.

When I implement on Controller class it is working properly.

But when I implment in the inner/service methods and tried to trigger @CircuitBreaker, its not working at all.

### first method

```
@CircuitBreaker(name =SOME_SERVICE,fallbackMethod = "getStubResponse") 
public String getResponse(String xml) {
        String result ;
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(some_url);
        post.setHeader("Accept", "text/xml");
        post.setHeader("Content-type", "text/xml");
        HttpEntity entity = null;
        try {
             entity = new ByteArrayEntity(xml.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            post.setEntity(entity);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
           
            throw new SomeException("UnsupportedEncodingException occured in SomeCall "+e);
        }

        try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
             CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post)) {
            result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        } catch (IOException io) {
            log.logError("OhubCall", "getResponseError", io.getMessage());
            throw new ArticlesException("IO Exception Occured in Call "+io);
        }
       
        return result;
        
    }
```

### Second Method

```
@CircuitBreaker(name =SOME_SERVICE,fallbackMethod = "getStubResponse")
  public String getResponse2(String xml) {
       String some_url = "some_servlet_url"
        WebClient client = WebClient.create();
        return client
                .post()
                .uri(some_url)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(xml))
                .exchange()
                .flatMap(response -> response.bodyToMono(String.class))
                .block();

    }
```

I am trying to implement @CircuitBreaker when the application/service class is calling a servlet.
I have also tried to implement @CircuitBreaker from the same inner service class and called another Rest Template call (another sample Spring Boot application) and its working properly.
So the problem seems to be with the HttpClient and WebClient.
Both are not triggering @CircuitBreaker.
Is there any work around for this problem.

Adding more information as per the comment :
We have working solution for

```
@Component 
public class ServiceClient {

@CircuitBreaker(name = "someservice", fallbackMethod = "SomeServiceFallback")
public String exampleCall() {

restTemplate.postForEntity()
}
```

Here the external service  we are calling using 'restTemplate.postForEntity()' is a Rest component.
This is working and  @CircuitBreaker is triggered.

But when the  external service is a servlet and not a rest service, @CircuitBreaker is not being triggered.
Instead of restTemplate.postForEntity(), we are using HttpClient to call external service.
It is not working,@CircuitBreaker is not being triggered

Comment: What do you mean with *inner service class*? AOP doesn't work on internal method calls.

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum , I have added more information to the question